# Safari: Text overlaps and doesn't respect container borders

Tags: ios, css, html, safari

I use an `html5` template for a simple website I'm currently making. Everything looks great in Firefox and Chrome, but on Safari (tested with MacBook and iPad Pro) the text is not rendered properly. It doesn't respect the container-width and sometimes words or letters even overlap. As soon as I mark the text, it's rendering properly.

Any idea what this could be about? The template uses google web fonts and imports them in the `css` file.

[Link to template demo](https://neuethemes.net/preview/html/fletcher/html/index01.html) for live-preview of the issue.

**Issue on MacBook (iOS 11)**

[image: MacBook: Text overlaps]

[image: MacBook: Text doesn't respect container borders]

[image: MacBook: Text overlaps & doesn't respect container borders]

**iPad Pro (iOS 11)**

[image: iPad Pro: Text doesn't respect container borders]

[image: iPad Pro: Text doesn't respect container borders]

Comment: For text overflowing the container do you have any `white-space: nowrap;`setup ?

Comment: Hi @t3__rry. Not in these places, where the overflowing takes place.

Answer (score 1):

from what I see there's two things: when disabling the `letter-spacing` from your `p` rule it's back to normal.

But most importantly, it seems that your `typography` styles is a `SCSS` file and is not compiled to `CSS` hence the display bug.

[image: From the network tab]

You might want to compile it to `CSS`and give it another try.
Hope it'll help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @t3__rry. You are right, there is a typography.scss file. In fact the file structure looks like this: https://ibb.co/njyrqn
So far, I only worked in the style.css file. What would you suggest to do with the typography.scss file to compile it to css? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know the techs involved in your project but if you're planning on minifying and creating a production build (which I highly recommend) you could use Webpack to do so.
If not I've found a tuts which explains how to do it with Node-Sass
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275

Comment: Sorry, for not coming back on this, @t3__ry. I got stuck in another project. I will let you know, when I had the chance to try... So far, I didn't minify the website at all and just uploaded it as it is to the server. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same issue on a website i have been working on, for the characters that are overlapping I beleive this is an issue with carriage returns, I copied the content of my text out of Invision and found it created these issues. when i removed the carriage returns the text read clearly, however i still have the issue with text overlapping it's container just as you do, I have a feeling this is a bug with letter-spacing in webkit browsers as i am having the same issue on an new ipad (interestingly an old ipad 2 I have sitting arround displays this perfectly).